# JSF button with dialog is not rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2

I created this example of JSF button with question dialog:

```
<!-- hidden button -->
<h:commandButton id="deleterow" value="HiddenDelete"  action="#{AccountProfileTabGeneralController.saveData}" style="display:none" update="growl">
    <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>

<!-- edit button -->
<h:button style="position:absolute; bottom:12px; right:12%;" rendered="#{AccountProfileTabGeneralController.editable}" styleClass="lbimage" value=" Save Account " onclick="editdialog(this, 'Do you want to save the changes?'); return false;" />
```

I use this JS to display the dialog:

```
function editdialog(button, a){      
    $("<div />", {
        text: a
    }).dialog({        
        width: 600,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function() { 
                $("#form\\:deleterow").click();
                $(this).dialog("close");
                button.value = "Processing...";
                button.disabled = true;                  
            }, 
            "Cancel": function(event) { 
                $(this).dialog("close");
                event.preventDefault();
                button.value = "Save Account";
                button.disabled = false;
            } 
        }
    });         
}
```

But for some reason then I click OK button the button is disabled and it's not working maybe the id of the form is not correct. I use this `<h:form id="general">`

How I can fix the problem? And also how I can use the code in forms with different id's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the form's id as "general", the jQuery selector should probably be

```
$("#general\\:deleterow")
```

but as you pointed out, you may have different forms, so that selector is very specific.

I would think you'd want something like:

```
$(button).closest("form").find("[id$=deleterow]").click();
```

What this does is find the first parent `form` element of the button that initiated the `editDialog` function, then find any element inside of that form that has an `id` that ends with "deleterow". This should work, since the `id` of that element will be something like "form_id:deleterow".